# Как выделить из даты месяц в pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датасет, в котором один признак - дата.
Как из полной даты (тип данных datetime64) например 2020-01-01 получить категориальный тип данных "январь" или "1"?
Пробовал делать через сплит - ошибка 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: df[“column_name”].dt.month

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
quarters_series = pd.Series(pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=3, freq="QE"))
>>> quarters_series
0   2000-03-31
1   2000-06-30
2   2000-09-30
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> quarters_series.dt.month
0    3
1    6
2    9
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).